# While loop automatically updates previous list values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, numerical-methods

I'm trying to implement the SOR algorithm in Python 3.X in order to solve an electrostatics problem. But, when inside the while loop, the break condition (relative error between previous and current iteration) appears to be fulfilled in the first iteration, which is certainly not correct. When troubleshooting the problem I found that the previous and current iterations have matching values:

```
def solve_laplace_SOR(w,tolerance,cant_puntos,step,volt):
   phi_vec=np.zeros(cant_puntos)# zero seed vector, stores previous iteration
   phi_vec_k1=np.zeros(cant_puntos) #Stores current iteration
   b_vec=load_ind_term(volt,cant_puntos) #independent term 
   E_vec=np.zeros(cant_puntos) #Electric field
   R_error=100 #Initializes relative error condition so as to enter the loop
   i=0 #counts iterations made

   #Initializes boundary conditions
   phi_vec_k1[0]=volt/2
   phi_vec_k1[cant_puntos-1]=-volt/2
   while R_error > tolerance: 
       phi_vec=phi_vec_k1[:] #Stores previous value as a copy, I checked this using id() function
       phi_vec_k1[1]=((b_vec[0]-phi_vec[2])/(-2)-phi_vec[1])*w+phi_vec[1]
       for x in range(2,cant_puntos-3):
           phi_vec_k1[x]=((b_vec[x-1]-phi_vec[x+1]-phi_vec_k1[x-1])/(-2)-phi_vec[x])*w+phi_vec[x]
           E_vec[x]=(-(phi_vec_k1[x+1]-phi_vec_k1[x-1])/(2*step)) 
           pass
       phi_vec_k1[cant_puntos-2]=((b_vec[cant_puntos-2]-phi_vec_k1[cant_puntos-3])/(-2)-  phi_vec[cant_puntos-2])*w+phi_vec[cant_puntos-2]
       E_vec[cant_puntos-2]=(-(phi_vec_k1[cant_puntos-1]-phi_vec_k1[cant_puntos-3])/(2*step))
       E_vec[1]=(-(phi_vec_k1[2]-phi_vec_k1[0])/(2*step))
       R_error=np.linalg.norm(np.array(phi_vec_k1)-np.array(phi_vec),1)/np.linalg.norm(phi_vec_k1,1)
       i+=1
       print(phi_vec_k1) #This outputs the same values
       print(phi_vec)
       pass
return E_vec
```

When setting an always true break condition, the function converges to expected values. Since i'm new to python and programming in general, i can't seem to find the reason for the unwanted update. I really hope you can, thanks very much!

Comment: Try using deepcopy() instead of [:]

Comment: That seems to be working for me, thanks!

Comment: Unless the array is object type, a simple `copy` is enough: `phi_vec_k1.copy()`